# psql is not connecting to the localhost if listen_address is different

Tags: bash, shell, psql, postgresql-9.2

I am trying to fetch some data using `psql` command. If I run the command directly in the console its working fine. The same command if I try to run from shell script, it says unable to connect to `psql` server. I have checked the `listen_address` variable in postgresql.conf, as I expected it was set to some name instead of `*` or `localhost`.

This server is running under cluster environment, so its using virtual ip in `listen_address`. The `pg_hba.conf` allowing `local` (IPv4 and IPv6) with `trust` authentication.

It makes sense to me so far. But, I'm confused why it isn't allowing through shell script on same server?

Edit 1:

```
myuser # psql -d mydb -U postgres -c "select 1"
 ?column? 
----------
    1
(1 row)

myuser # cat myscript.sh
psql -d mydb -U postgres -c "select 1"

myuser # sh myscript.sh
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Comment: Maybe include the command you are running...

Comment: It was bit huge. Anyway even, if I try to run ```psql -d dbname -c "select 1"``` didn't work from shell script.

Comment: How are you running the shell script? What error do you get when running it?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Are you using bash? Why are you running the script with sh? Also what port is postgres running on? Can you post the output of the command `env` output both in and out of the script?

Comment: @123 yes, Im using. I tried with bash too. Added ```#!/bin/bash``` at beginning of the script and executed ```/bin/bash myscript.sh```, same error.

Comment: It looks like psql is using different connection and/or authentication methods when it is used interactively and within a script (I don't know why). You write that the server is configured to listen to local TCP/IP connections, but then you expect it to accept a socket connection. Try to force TCP/IP connection with password authentication, if you succeed then move on to more convenient connection. See remarks for trust authentication https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-TRUST

Comment: @dr_agon, I can't go with ```trust``` due to some policy. Anyway, your answer gave me clue and used socket connection. It worked. Thanks :)